# load data from hdfs into spark2.1 table using thriftserver and beeline error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My development environment are:

- spark version: 2.1.0 (spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7)
- jdk:1.7
- hadoop: hadoop-2.7.2
- hive: 1.2.1
- deloy mode: spark on yarn
- And I set hive-site.xml

```html
<property>
  <name>hive.exec.stagingdir</name>
  <value>/tmp/hive/spark-${user.name}</value>
  </property>
```

- When I load data from hdfs into spark table using thriftserver and beeline error:

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to move source hdfs://hadoop.td.com/user/zxh/testdata/td/dbdata to destination hdfs://hadoop.td.com/warehouse/spark/dmpv3.db/at/dbdata

**Is this spark2.1 bug??
How can I fix it??  thanks!!**

All the error information:

```js
17/08/23 17:21:43 INFO thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Running query 'LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/zxh/testdata/td/dbdata' INTO TABLE at' with 3d810df4-55c8-48b7-a889-091b5dabe284
17/08/23 17:21:43 INFO execution.SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/zxh/testdata/td/dbdata' INTO TABLE at
17/08/23 17:21:43 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 53: get_database: dmpv3
17/08/23 17:21:43 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hadoop ip=unknown-ip-addr cmd=get_database: dmpv3 
17/08/23 17:21:43 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 53: get_table : db=dmpv3 tbl=at
17/08/23 17:21:43 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hadoop ip=unknown-ip-addr cmd=get_table : db=dmpv3 tbl=at 
17/08/23 17:21:43 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 53: get_table : db=dmpv3 tbl=at
17/08/23 17:21:43 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hadoop ip=unknown-ip-addr cmd=get_table : db=dmpv3 tbl=at 
17/08/23 17:21:43 INFO parser.CatalystSqlParser: Parsing command: string
17/08/23 17:21:43 INFO parser.CatalystSqlParser: Parsing command: string
17/08/23 17:21:43 INFO parser.CatalystSqlParser: Parsing command: string
17/08/23 17:21:43 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 53: get_database: dmpv3
17/08/23 17:21:43 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hadoop ip=unknown-ip-addr cmd=get_database: dmpv3 
17/08/23 17:21:44 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 53: get_table : db=dmpv3 tbl=at
17/08/23 17:21:44 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hadoop ip=unknown-ip-addr cmd=get_table : db=dmpv3 tbl=at 
17/08/23 17:21:44 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 53: get_table : db=dmpv3 tbl=at
17/08/23 17:21:44 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hadoop ip=unknown-ip-addr cmd=get_table : db=dmpv3 tbl=at 
17/08/23 17:21:44 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 53: get_table : db=dmpv3 tbl=at
17/08/23 17:21:44 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=hadoop ip=unknown-ip-addr cmd=get_table : db=dmpv3 tbl=at 
17/08/23 17:21:44 ERROR thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Error executing query, currentState RUNNING, 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_14.loadTable(HiveShim.scala:716)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveClientImpl.scala:672)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:672)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:672)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:283)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:230)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:229)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:272)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.loadTable(HiveClientImpl.scala:671)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:741)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:739)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:739)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:95)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.loadTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:739)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.loadTable(SessionCatalog.scala:319)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.LoadDataCommand.run(tables.scala:302)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:185)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:592)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:699)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$thriftserver$SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$execute(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:220)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$1$$anon$2.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:163)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$1$$anon$2.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:160)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$1.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:173)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to move source hdfs://hadoop.td.com/user/zxh/testdata/td/dbdata to destination hdfs://hadoop.td.com/warehouse/spark/dmpv3.db/at/dbdata
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.moveFile(Hive.java:2644)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.copyFiles(Hive.java:2711)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadTable(Hive.java:1645)
 ... 47 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:808)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getEZForPath(DFSClient.java:3288)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getEZForPath(DistributedFileSystem.java:2093)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.HdfsAdmin.getEncryptionZoneForPath(HdfsAdmin.java:289)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims$HdfsEncryptionShim.isPathEncrypted(Hadoop23Shims.java:1221)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.moveFile(Hive.java:2607)
 ... 49 more
17/08/23 17:21:44 ERROR thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Error running hive query: 
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$thriftserver$SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$execute(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:258)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$1$$anon$2.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:163)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$1$$anon$2.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:160)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$1.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:173)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you add the query you have tried? It's(`'LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/zxh/testdata/td/dbdata' INTO TABLE`) not complete one it seems.

Comment: thank you @mrsrinivas but my table name is at

Answer (score 0):

I use spark-1.6.2 thriftserver and beeline, and use spark-2.1+yarn core, and the question does not exists.
But There is no guarantee that there are other problems!

Answer (score 0):

It's bug. Include Spark 2.1 2.2 (I tried.)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21725

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11083

Comment: Now , i use Spark1.6.3's thriftserver for beeline. And other Spark-sql use Spark2.x